# How to index a Matlab array inside a CUDA kernel

Tags: c++, matlab, matrix, cuda

I am working on parallelizing a Program written in Matlab.

At the moment I have the following code:

```
#define _USE_MATH_DEFINES

#include "cuda_runtime.h"
#include "device_launch_parameters.h"

#include <math.h>

__global__ void radialAverage(double** image, int x_center, int y_center)
{
    int i, x, y;

    const int x_size = 400;
    const int y_size = 400;

    int thread = blockIdx.x*blockDim.x+threadIdx.x;

    double angle     = 0;
    double dAngle    = M_PI/360;

    double radImgMat[x_size][y_size];
    double angleMatPi[x_size][y_size];


    //radImMap erstellen
    for( x = 0; x < x_size; x++) {
        for( y = 0; y < y_size; y++) {
        radImgMat[x][y]  = sqrt((double)(x+1-x_center)*(x+1-x_center) + (y+1-y_center)*(y+1-y_center));
        }
    }

    //Angle-Matrix (pi-pi) erstellen
    for ( x = 0; x < x_size; x++) {
        for( y = 0; y < y_size; y++) {
            float xD = x+1-x_center;
            float yD = y+1-y_center;
            if(yD>0) {
                angleMatPi[x][y] = -1*(atan(xD/yD)+M_PI/2)+M_PI;
            } else if(yD==0 && xD<0) {
                angleMatPi[x][y] = M_PI;
            } else if(yD==0 && xD>0) {
                angleMatPi[x][y] = 0;
            } else {
                angleMatPi[x][y] = -1*(atan(xD/yD)+M_PI/2);
            }
        }
    }

    //Cut ImgMat
    for(x=0; x < x_size; x++) {
        for(y = 0; y < y_size; y++) {
            if((angleMatPi[x][y] < (angle-dAngle)) || (angleMatPi[x][y] > (angle+dAngle))) {
                image[x][y] = 0;
            }               
        }
    }
}
```

In pure C++ it works perfectly well but I get errors when I try to
Index the `int* image` matrix, which should be 2D. Does anyone of you
have an idea on how to access the content of the given matrix?

Comment: You may have gotten your code to compile with `int** image`, but that's about as far as you'll get, unless you carefully process the link given by @talonmies, as well as the answer given below.

Comment: In case you haven't noticed, your code formatting is a complete mess.  Lines of code should be formatted separately from your question text by indenting 4 spaces.  Don't put the special formatting character `>` at the beginning of every line you post.  If you want to post questions here, please make it easy for others to read by figuring out appropriate formatting, and re-editing your question until the formatting is correct.

Comment: oh! I didn't noticed it by now :/ sry  Edit: I updated the Question

Answer (score 0):

I see three problems with the code. First of all we need to make sure that the image data is copied to the GPU and passed to the kernel. You may have done this, but we would need to see the host code to know. The code that runs on the host should look like this,

```
int *d_image;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_image,x_size*y_size*sizeof(int)); //allocate memory on the GPU for the image

cudaMemcpy(d_image,image,x_size*y_size*sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice); //copy the image to GPU global memory

radialAverage<<<numBlocks,numThreads>>>(d_image,x_size,y_size,x_center,y_center); //Call CUDA kernel with device pointer to image data
```

That should solve the crashing when referencing the image data. Second is the way you are indexing image. If you pass image as an int* you must access it as a 1D array. The CUDA code has no idea what the dimensions of image are. Whenever you want to grab some image data you need to use this (assuming row major order),

```
image[y*x_size + x];
```

Third is that your code is not parallel at all. You never once reference the value of 'thread' during the computation so you are basically doing the same serial computation on the whole image many times in parallel. I would suggest looking over some very basic CUDA code to get an idea of how this works. UDACITY has a great little online video class on CUDA and parallel coding that I highly recommend. https://www.udacity.com/course/cs344

Comment: Mostly valid points, however since the OP mentions matlab, presumably using the mex or PTX interface, there is no "host code" to inspect.  Matlab does all the setup internally prior to calling the supplied kernel.

Comment: Yeah that is my problem :/ But I think I can solve it when I reshape the image and do the 1D Array thingy :D

Comment: That I'm doing the same computation is because I wanted to test the code to the actual point before adding the actual parallel part (radial average part)...